# NSMutableArray index Difficulty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When deleting `iCarousel` view, like this:

`[carousel removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];`

How to maintain/Retain the deleted views/index even going to different `viewController`?. Because in my experience of it, it returns its view back,  Or putting the deleted index in an array?  is this possible?

Already have tried adding the array to the `app delegate`, but still no luck. 
Haven't tried `singleton` yet. But is there other way, Thanks for the help.

Comment: before remove save those indexes in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an array in AppDelegate and put indexes to that array. But before, you should create NSNumber objects from NSInteger(int) this way:

```
// This line should be in your delegate
NSMutableArray *indexesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

// In your controller: 
NSInteger index = 1; // Use your index instead
NSNumber *indexObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.indexesArray addObject:indexObject];
```

The same is for views. You can store UIView objects in NSMutableArray as well.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[appDelegate.viewsArray addObject:view];
```

Comment: What i want is even when i delete an index it will be retain even if i go to another view?